# Are there any bases which represent all rationals in a finite number of digits?

Tags: rational-numbers, number-systems, decimal-expansion

In base 10, 1/3 cannot be represented in a finite number of digits. Examples exist in many other bases (notably base 2, as it's relevant to computing). I'm wondering: does there exist any base in which every rational number can be represented in a finite number of digits? My intuition is that the answer is no. If so, what is a proof of this?

Comment: You might be interested in [mixed radix systems,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) such as the factorial system, in which integers are represented as $\sum a_k k!$, where $0\le a_k\le k$. The natural extension to real numbers has the property that all rationals have a terminating representation.

Comment: If you want another system where all rationals can be expressed in a finite number of digits, consider looking into _continued fractions_.

Comment: Those look interesting; thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your intuition is correct for instance for all $b > 2$, $\frac{1}{b-1}$ is not going to have a finite representation, and will have the representation
$\frac{1}{b-1} = 0.1111111...._b.$ Eg, $\frac{1}{9} = .11111111$ in base 10.

Comment: When you say "is not going to have a repeating representation", don't you mean that it will have a repeating representation? Also, consider $b=2$. $\dfrac{1}{2-1}=\dfrac{1}{1}=1=0.11111...$ but it has a non-repeating representation

Comment: @Quincunx You are correct, edited to reflect issues.

Comment: What about b < 2? (assuming those systems can even represent rational numbers)

Comment: If you want an example that also works in base 2, you could use $1/(b^2-1)$ which has base $b$ expansion $0.01010101\dots_b$.

Answer (score 24):

A representation, though not positional, which yields a finite string for rational numbers is the Stern-Brocot representation which derives from the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-stern-brocot) (also [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Stern.shtml)).

The Stern-Brocot tree is a *binary* tree which can be used to enumerate all the rationals and which has useful applications in the rational approximation of real numbers. Here is a portion of this curious tree (the horizontal axis has a logarithmic scale):

[image]

Since the nodes of this special tree are in one-to-one correspondence with the rationals, one can represent each rational by a string which specifies how to walk down the tree, starting from the root 1/1, to reach the given rational. Since the tree is binary, a rational can be specified by a string of **L**(eft) and **R**(ight) letters. The representation is finite because all fractions can be reached with a finite number of turns.

For example, the fraction 8/5 can be specified by **RLRL**.

Real numbers have, instead, an infinite representation. For example, the golden ratio has the nice representation **RLRLRLRLRL...**

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with the question, which clearly asks about expansions in positional systems.

Comment: @JiK The OP might not have been aware of the existence of non-positional systems, and this is just an example. Consider it as an extended comment.

Comment: Can you do arithmetic with this representation?

Comment: @PyRulez It appears yes, see [Exact arithmetic on the Stern–Brocot tree](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866706000311).

Answer (score 10):

A rational number $x$ has a finite digital expansion in base $b$ if and only if it's expressible as $a/b^n$ for an integer $a$ and some $n\ge1$. In particular $u/v$ (written in simplest terms) cannot be written in base $b$ if and only if the denominator $v>1$ has a prime factor that $b$ doesn't.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I might find a proof of this?

Comment: @synful I suggest trying to prove it yourself, it's very easy. Think about what multiplying by a power of $10$ does to a number's decimal expansion.

Comment: @synful If $x$ has finite digital expansion in base $b$, that means it's a finite sum of powers (possibly negative powers) of $b$. If there are any negative powers, add the fractions using the highest power of $b$ as the LCD to obtain a fraction of the form $a/b^n$. Conversely, given $a/b^n$, we can write $a$ in base $b$ and then just shift $n$ digits to the right.

Answer (score 5):

In standard positional notation, no. Just pick any number p which is relatively prime to the base and 1/p will not terminate.

There is however a delightful way of doing this if we play a little bit loose and lovely with what is a "base", called "factorial base" (if you Google it, their are 6 million hits!). This has the exact property you ask for. Even if it doesn't meet your needs, it is a very interesting idea.

Comment: See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Fractional_values