# Is there any basis transformation under which all irrational numbers are rationals and vice-versa?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, number-systems

For example, if you change the length of your "unit scale" or basis for numbers to $\sqrt{2}$, then you may represent all fractional multiples of $\sqrt{2}$ as "rational numbers" in the new basis system. Is there any complicated transformation on numbers possible like basis/"base" changes, etc mapping rationals to irrationals and vice-versa. If not, what is the reason for this "bias" between rationals and irrationals?

Comment: Hint: the rationals are countable set and irrational is not.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [Are there any bases which represent all rationals in a finite number of digits?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169872/are-there-any-bases-which-represent-all-rationals-in-a-finite-number-of-digits/1170277#1170277)

Comment: A fractional multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ is still an irrational number, regardless of how it's been represented. You maybe have a meaningful idea in your head, but if so, it needs to be explained more if you wish to convey it. (although as the comments and answer has shown, people can sort of guess at things that are probably responses to what you have in mind anyways, even if it's not clear what you have in mind)

Comment: Cantor has proven that impossible, leading to the breakthrough result that irrationals are "more numerous" that rationals.

Answer (score 30):

It is unclear exactly what kind of "basis transformations" you want to allow, but presumably any such thing would be a bijection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  But there is no bijection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which exchanges the irrationals and the rationals, because it would restrict to a bijection between the rationals and the irrationals, and the rationals are countable and the irrationals are uncountable.